# Auto translate plugin text-domain

Tags: plugin-recommendation, translation

I'm searching for a plugin that automatically translate plugins.

I don't want plugins like [polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) or [gtranslate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gtranslate/), I don't want to have more than one language in my website(The website has only one page), and I want to have the ability to edit the translations after they're been auto translated.

I don't want a plugin like [loco-translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/), I need a plugin that will automatically translate the plugin text-domain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about plugins that would do that, but I can definitely recommend this software: https://poedit.net/

It won't translate automatically every phrase, but it suggests pretty accurate string translations. The pro version also has the option to retrieve all translation ready strings from a theme or plugin. It lets you to easily update and edit the existing translations and compile it to .po and .mo files.

As a side note I'd say that it's never entirely safe to rely on automated translations, we're simply not there yet with the technology, you will always get something really akward or nonsense from time to time, especially if you're translating into less popular languages.